# Get the name of the collection which is currently using to store the documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

From the documentation of [MongoEngine](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-collections) I have found that user can set preferred `collection name`.

```
class Users(Document):
    user_id = SequenceField(primary_key=True)
    meta = {'collection': "test_collection"}
```

Is there a way where I can get this collection name (here **test_collection**) later by sending query? My purpose is to `do something` after checking the existance of a `collection`.
The solution I have found that after getting the `db name` and `list of collections` checking the existance but here the limitation is I have to write by myself the required `collection name`.

```
db = get_db() # This one from connect parameter get the set database name
col = db.list_collection_names() # get all collections name of used database from the previous line
print("existance checking: ", "test_collection" in db.list_collection_names()) # here I don't want to hard coded the collection name "test_collection"
```

I have tried the following but get error

```
for x in Users.objects:
    print("meta: ", x.meta)
```

Error_message:

```
AttributeError: 'Users' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

Reason of trying the former approach as I have got valid result from

```
for x in Users.objects:
  print("user_id: ", x.user_id)
```

I am new in MongoDB so don't know how it works or whether it possible or not. So, if there is any query to acheive the current collection name specified in the `Users` class by PyMongo/ MongoEngine would be really helpful.

Comment: If you have an instance of the `Users` class, then I think you can get the collection name from the `meta` property (like other properties). E.g., `user.meta`, `user.user_id`, etc.

Comment: @prasad_ I don't think so. `user.user_id` means may be setting new value for "user_id". Though I have checked with `user.meta` but is given me error. `AttributeError: 'Users' object has no attribute 'meta'`. I have edited the question also by adding some approach those I have taken in this regard.